# Operating System scheduling

Tags: operating-systems

I was reading a book on Operating System by Galvin and came across this :
In the latest version of Solaris, scheduling is controlled by loadable tables. Depending on the table currently loaded, the system can be time-sharing, batch processing, real-time, fair share, or any combination. Making the scheduling mechanism general-purpose allows profound policy changes to be made with a single load-new-table command.
Can someone explain what are these loadable tables.
Thanks in advance :)